# Table View Commit Editing Style in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

i have this code, i want to convert this into the swift code.

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

i am getting a delete editing style by default, i want None Style.
Thanks in advance.!!

Comment: And what exactly is the problem you're running into?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the proper declaration of the method by command-clicking on the `UITableViewDelegate` identifier in a Swift source file or playground.  This makes Xcode show you the Swift-ified version of `UITableView.h`.  In there, you can search for `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` to find the exact method signature.  Once you have that, the rest is easy:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return .None
}
```

Note that Swift deduces that `None` is a member of the `UITableViewCellEditingStyle` enumeration because of the declared return type of the method.